# Prevent span inside `contenteditable` div being deleted

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an editable div containing a span which I do not want the user to be able to delete. I'm using Vue3.

Currently when the user presses backspace with their cursor to the right of the span, or presses delete after selecting the div's contents with `ctrl+A`, the span is deleted.

```js
<div class="editable-div" contenteditable>
    <span contenteditable="false">some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using two separate elements, one containing the text you want with `contenteditable`, another you want without `contenteditable`. The two texts appear together in the parent `div`.

```html
<div class="editable-div">
    <span>some text</span>
    <span contenteditable>other text</span>
</div>
```

This code will work best if your not editable text precedes or succeeds your editable text.